# How to start session and destroy session and again start new session and destroy in php?

Tags: javascript, php

In my code error and error1 is working properly but at the time of error2 it is not showing. And error, error1 and error2 have to display at same place according to how user treat the email and password box. And error2 have to show in green color.

**login.php**

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
if($email!=''&&$password!='')
{
$q = "select * from user where uemail='$email' and password='$password'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $q);
$num = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($num == 1){
Header( 'Location: home.php');
exit;
}else{
$_SESSION['error']= "Incorrect email or password!";
$_SESSION['error1']= "Try again later!";
Header( 'Location: index.php');
exit;
}
}else{
$_SESSION['error2']= "Please enter in box";
Header( 'Location: index.php');
exit;
}
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['error'])){
echo '<div  id="display">' . $_SESSION['error'] .  '</div><script 
type="text/javascript">  
function showIt() {  
document.getElementById("display").style.visibility = "hidden";  
}  
setTimeout("showIt()", 3000); 
function showIt() {
    document.getElementById("display").style.cssText = "color: green";
    document.getElementById("dislpay").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("dislpay").innerHTML = "'.$_SESSION["error1"].'";
}
</script>';
}
unset ($_SESSION['error1']);
unset ($_SESSION['error']); 
session_destroy ();
?>
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['error2'])){
echo '<div  id="display">' . $_SESSION['error2'] .  '</div>';
}
unset ($_SESSION['error2']); 
session_destroy ();
?>
```

Comment: Session_Start(); needs to be present on every page you wish to use sessions

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct but you have to initialize `session_start()` on every page.